# Bash Script - Not collateral after echo due to new line

Tags: bash, echo

I'm trying to get below output but always output comes with one more newline. How can I obtain desired output?

Desired output:  **3 number of line detected**

Actual output:

**3**

**number of line is detected.**

```
linecount= awk '{/^./ && c++};END{print c}' < test.txt //// (or cat text.txt | wc -l (both is ok))

if [ -s test.txt ]; then
        echo  $linecount number of line detected
        echo
else
        echo No line detected.
        echo
```

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: use `printf` instead of `print`